# automatically apply Chop to outputs?

Tags: output

Is there a common trick to automatically show output with "Chop" applied? I typically get results like below, which hinders readability

```
{{1., -2.08167*10^-16, -1.73472*10^-18}, {-2.08167*10^-16, 1., 
  3.19189*10^-16}, {-1.73472*10^-18, 3.19189*10^-16, 1.}}
```

Comment: Run `$Post = Chop;` and try again.

Comment: `$Post = # /. x_Real /; 0 < Abs[x] < 10^-10 :> SetAccuracy[x, -Log10@Abs[x]]&` might be preferred sometimes. Since what should be zero is relative, this shows how big the number being treated as zero is.

Comment: The problem with `$Post`, imo, is that it is applied to *every output.*  I don't think I'd want `Chop` applied to every output.  Hence I don't use it, but apply formatters by hand & when appropriate.

Comment: Do you want your results to be chopped or do you want to show chopped results?

Comment: What Kuba is saying is that there is `$Post`, which affects what is stored in `Out` (i.e. the value of `%`) and there is `$PrePrint`, which only affects how it is shown on screen. I think `$Post` has a high potential for confusion because `x=Sin[1]`, `x+1` is going to be different from `Sin[1]`, `%+1`.

Comment: I have marked this question as "already has an answer" -- if you feel that the linked Q&A is not the same please edit your question to clarify your intent.